# PHP Post not getting data from AngularJS

Tags: php, html, angularjs, post

I'm working on a small AngularJS/PHP website - this is just the login screen, and i can't figure out what the issue with the PHP side is.  If i hardcode the name\password in PHP, it queries the MariaDB fine and everything works.

I do have to fix this up security wise - cause responding with either bad username or bad password is terrible.  I just need to get it working properly first.

The Angular controller:

```
app.controller ("logController", function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.btnLogin = true;
        $scope.btnLogout = false;
        $scope.btnMenu = false;
        $scope.errorMsg = false;
        $scope.adminMenu = false;

        $scope.logout = function() {
            $rootScope.usrName = "";
            $scope.btnLogin = true;
            $scope.btnLogout = false;
            $scope.btnMenu = false;
            $scope.adminMenu = false;
            $location.url('home');
        };

        $scope.loginForm = function() {
            var ans="";
            var encodedString = 'name=' +
                 encodeURIComponent(this.user.name) +
                 '&password=' +
                 encodeURIComponent(this.user.password);
            $http({
                    method  : 'POST',
                    url     : 'php/login.php',
                    //params: {
                    //  name: this.user.name,
                    //  password: this.user.password
                    //}
                    data        : encodedString,
                    headers : {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                }).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    ans = response.data;
                    if (ans.message == 'correct' ) {
                        $rootScope.usrName = ans.usrname;
                        $rootScope.usrLevel = ans.userlevel;
                        $rootScope.name = ans.name;
                        $scope.btnLogin = false;
                        $scope.btnLogout = true;
                        $scope.btnMenu = true;
                        if ($rootScope.usrLevel == '1') {
                            $scope.adminMenu = true;
                        }
                        $('#loginModal').modal('hide');
                    } else {
                        $scope.errorMsg = true;
                        $scope.error = ans.error;
                    }
                },
                function (response) {
                //error handling
            });
        };
    });
```

The PHP (note im using RedBean ORM for db communication).
In the JSON being responded back i can see that $name (from the $_POST) is null.

```
<?php
    //ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    //error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    require_once ("connect.php");
    require_once ("rb.php");

    //var_dump($_POST);
    
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    //$name = "John-Smith";
    //$password = "password";
    $result = false;
    //echo $_POST;

    //As all Error Reporting is turned on - we need to create a response object, so it wont throw an error later;
    if (!isset($resp) || !is_object($resp)) {
        $resp = new \stdClass();
    }

    $user = R::find('staff', ' name LIKE ? ', [ $name ] );
    //echo $user;
    //print_r("user: ", $user);
    if (Empty($user)) {
        $errors = 'Invalid Username';
    }

    //$user is returned as a 2 dimensional arrary - so we need to iterate thru it, even though it should only have 1 element.
    foreach ($user as $usr) {
        if ($usr->password == $password) {
            $thisusr = $usr;
            $result = true;
        } else {
            $errors = 'Your Password is incorrect';
        }
    }

    if ($result == true) {
        $data->message = "correct";
        $data->usrname = $thisusr->username;
        $data->userlevel = $thisusr->userlevel;
        $data->name = $thisusr->name;

    } else {
        $data->message = "fail";
        $data->error = $errors;
        $data->name = $name;
        //$data->password = $password
        $data->user = $user;
        
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```